# how to create foreign key use migration code first (one to many relationship)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 classes:

public class Retete

```
{
    public Retete() { }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nume { get; set; }
    public string Categorie { get;  set; }
    public string Grupa { get; set; }
    public string Descriere { get; set; }
    public string Ingrediente { get; set; }
    public string Preparare { get; set; }


    //Configure 1 to many relationship
    //Foreign Key

    [ForeignKey("GrupaIndivizi")]
    public int GrupaID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GrupaID")]
    public virtual GrupaIndivizi GrupaIndivizi { get; set; }
}
```

and

public class GrupaIndivizi

```
{
    public GrupaIndivizi(){}

    [Key]
    public int GrupaID { get; set; }
    public string NumeGrupa { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Retete> Retetes { get; set; }
}
```

and the table that are created

[image]

My question is how to make GrupaID from Retetes table to be a foreign Key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make a foreign key in entity framework is:  beside the Id of the key you need to have an object of that type. Check if this works.

```
[Table("Retete")] 
public class Retete
        {
            public Retete() { }

            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Nume { get; set; }
            public string Categorie { get;  set; }
            public string Grupa { get; set; }
            public string Descriere { get; set; }
            public string Ingrediente { get; set; }
            public string Preparare { get; set; }


            //Configure 1 to many relationship
            //Foreign Key

            [ForeignKey("GrupaIndivizis")]
            public int GrupaIndiviziID { get; set; }
            public GrupaIndivizi GrupaIndivizi { get; set; }
        }
```

I would also recommed to get the tables some more suitable names and don't let EF generate the names. This can be done by the `Table` attribute. 
Your FK didn't generate corectly because he was trying to bind to a `GrupaIndivizi` table but you have `GrupaIndivizis`.

Comment: I tried this method, and after i run add-migration in the Package Manager Console, i`m getting this error:                                              The property 'GrupaID' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection<T> where T is a valid entity type.

Comment: remove the `GrupaID` from your `Retete` class and retry

Comment: It still does not work.GrupaIndiviziID is not a foreign Key, is just a column from table Retetes.

Comment: I don`t get any error message, the table is created, but in the Retete table, is not created the foreign key. I tried with following code:   [Table("Retete")]
    public class Retete
    {
        public Retete() { }
        public int ID { get; set; }
       ...
      //  [Key]
        [ForeignKey("GrupaIndivizis")]
        public int GrupaIndiviziID { get; set; }
       // public int GrupaID { get; set; }
      //  [ForeignKey("GrupaID")]

        public GrupaIndivizi GrupaIndivizis { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Thanks for your help,  your solution was ok, I didn`t check in the Show Data Table from server explorer if the foreign key is created. 
I thought that the foreign key must show in server explorer.